# Yearling Badge Gets Awarded Weekly

Tags: support

I keep getting the [Yearling Badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/13/yearling) awarded to me like about every week. It was just awarded to me today, July 14th, July 4th, and back in 2013.

Seems strange to be getting this badge awarded about every week. Any ideas why this would be happening? Do I just not understand how the badge works?

Comment: @yellowantphil So it's 1 badge per 200 rep per year? Not just per year?

Comment: @yellowantphil Ok makes a bit more sense. Kinda strange system that isn't documented the best haha. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @CharlieFish /OT Seems you're having a very fast life. Consult Einstein how to slow it down using gravity.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ What? How does that relate at all?

Comment: @CharlieFish I said /OT. You know humor, do you? BTW regarding the facts, gravitiy actually influences time. You should have been told that in your basic physics course.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I just didn't understand it at first...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably it's answered in comments already, but still: every *nth* Yearling badge requires *(n*200)+1* reputation to get.

So if you have a member for four years and had 301 reputation, you have only got the Yearling badge for the first year, since you the second year would require 401 reps, the third - 601 and the forth - 801.

If then you suddenly happen to get a 400rep bounty one day (thus having 701 rep), you immediately get your second and third badge in that day, since you're now above 601. The next day, you spend your reputation on a 300rep bounty, but you do keep three earling badges you've earned (now having 401 rep). The forth Yearling badge does still requre 801 rep to get however.

---

Let's look at the different scenario. In the first year, you earn 1500 reps on a stack, but then, before the first year elapses, you spend 1400 of these reps on bounties. Then three years pass and you get another 200 rep meanwhile. You're now at 301 rep, and have got just *one* Yearling badge, since you didn't have enough rep by the time the second, third and forth year passed.